# Unable to display the Bootstrap Carousel correctly in Angular2+

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here, I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Angular 4. My issue is that I am trying to display the number of pics in Bootstrap Carousel and in each slide I am trying to display 3 pics. Till now, I am getting data from an array and here after the last pic ends. Then, the first pic has to follow instantly but now I am getting all my images in a single page. Below is my code:

**.html code:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  >
      <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let data of  DataOne;let i = index" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel"  [attr.data-slide-to]="i" class="active"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="{{data.ImageUrl}}" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:50%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts code:**

```
 export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  DataOne:any=[
    {    
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    { 
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    {  
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    {   
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    {    
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    {   
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
     },
     {
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    },
    {    
      "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
    }
  ];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Below are solutions which I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Did you add css for this?. Show your index.html and angularcli.json

Comment: i added bootstrap and added it in style.css

Comment: Kindly show which link you followed.

Comment: which link means normally i went to bootstrap official site and sorted it

Comment: Just for a suggestion go this link see added css and js in head section use like this in your project https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h

Comment: i will and if possible could u create a sample with my Json

Comment: Sure I will reach office few minute I will send you stackblitz for you. Currently Iam travelling bus

Comment: sure i will check other things also

Comment: visit this demo site. https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/ . you want like this?

Comment: actually what i am trying to achieve is multiple items per slide in bootstrap carousel

Comment: actually like this https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY and the content will be displayed in cards

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap carousel each `.item` is the actual slider. So, if you want to have a slider with 3 images inside, you have to place your `.col-sm-4` and loop it tree times inside the `.item`. You may have to update your images object.

See: https://angular-52pqo7.stackblitz.io

Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52pqo7

Data Json:

```
DataOne:any=[{
        "sliderImages": [{
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            },
            {
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            },
            {
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sliderImages": [{
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            },
            {
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            },
            {
                "ImageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSW6QPbLZN-2Xs4Jb6DMZKivwTQtw5L3QH5AjJf4fPM8pubZato2Q"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Carousel:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  >
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" 
          *ngFor="let data of  DataOne; first as isFirst;"
          [class.active]="(isFirst)"
        >
          <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let slidImg of  data.sliderImages">
            <img src="{{slidImg.ImageUrl}}" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:50%;">
          </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
        </div><!-- .item -->
      </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li 
          *ngFor="let data of  DataOne; index as i; first as isFirst;" 
          data-target="#myCarousel"  
          [attr.data-slide-to]="(i)"
          [class.active]="(isFirst)"></li>
      </ol>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div><!-- #myCarousel -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: bu why separated json ? we can process via single list also right  and i applied your data in the backend and in the front end also it is not working

Comment: Separate it for your easier understand on how bootstrap carousel works. You can make your changes on the loop logic...

Comment: It's hard to guess what is going on on your application as you have not provided your application code.. Have you checked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52pqo7 it is working, set yours https://stackblitz.com then we can have a look

Comment: why the image one after another actually it has to be like one by one or on next to another

Comment: Please read [CSS Bootstrap - Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to understand